# Is it possible to produce HTML output using KNITR in LYX?

Tags: html, r, knitr, lyx

Some web searching didn't give me any answer to this question. Is there any chance to produce a HTML output using KNITR under LYX? Alternatively, can I use any converter to get a HTML (DOC, ODT, as well) output from a PDF first generated in KNITR under LYX?